# Promise in meanjs app controller "then" is not a function

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, angular-promise

In my meanjs app created using meanjs generator and auto generated CRUD-module, for income below, I want to customize the promise returned by the get method so that I can call methods and do transformations on the retrieved data. So i attempt to change it in my controller:

```
// Find existing Income
    $scope.findOne = function() {
        Incomes.get({
            incomeId: $stateParams.incomeId
    }).then(function(income){
       $scope.income = income;
       $scope.incomeDollar= income*$scope.dollarRate;
    });
```

This only gives me the error : undefined is not a function, and pointing on then.
What am i doing wrong here? How can I do transformations on the data retrieved from the get method above?

The pattern i am trying to use is in the end of the article [here](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/). I want to switch from the short version to the long so that i can do more stuff in my callback.

```
// LONG:

myModule.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, HelloWorld) {

  HelloWorld.getMessages().then(function(messages) {
    $scope.messages = messages;
  });

});
```

To simplify this, the writer of the article place the promise returned by ‘getMessages’ on the scope:

```
// SHORTER:

myModule.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, HelloWorld) {

  $scope.messages = HelloWorld.getMessages();

});
```

Comment: Could you post the definition of Incomes service?

Comment: I am using an abstract workflow, the Incomes service have not been customized for get, only put. As shown in [this template](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/blob/master/crud-module/templates/angular-module/services/_.client.service.js) that has been used

Comment: The shorter way of getMessages is no longer available in Angular (1.3), check out: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise object can be accessed using $promise. From the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

> The Resource instances and collection have these additional
>   properties:
>
> $promise: the promise of the original server interaction that created
>   this instance or collection.
>
> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or
>   collection object, updated with data from server...

So, your code should look like:

```
// Find existing Income
$scope.findOne = function() {
    Incomes.get({
        incomeId: $stateParams.incomeId
}).$promise.then(function(income){
   $scope.income = income;
   $scope.incomeDollar= income*$scope.dollarRate;
});
```